# Switching between frames in python with functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wish to have two functions in which I have frames that I can easily switch between. I can remove the "go" frame but I am unsure how to show another frame afterward.

```
from tkinter import *

class Trip:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.go = Frame(parent, width=500, height=450)
        self.go.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.go.grid_propagate(0)  # to reserve space required for frame
        menuButton = Button(self.go, text="Continue", command=self.menuScreen)
         menuButton.grid(row=1, column=0)


    def menuScreen(self):
        self.go.grid_remove()
        self.menu = Frame(parent, width=500, height=450, bg='orchid')
        self.menu.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.menu.grid_propagate(0)  # to reserve space required for frame

        self.addMore = Button(self.menuScreen, text="Return", command=self.__init__)
        self.addmore.grid(row=1, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Traveller Details")
    play = Trip(root)
    root.geometry("500x450+0+0")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope of `parent` seems to be confined to `constructor` initialization. You are calling `parent` again in `menuScreen` function.

Try defining a local variable within class say `parent` and pass `parent1` as argument to the constructor. That way `parent` attribute is visible throughout the class.

I was able to advance to next screen using above, although it ran into some other issues which I believe may be dependent on other part of your code that's not presented here.

Here is modified code.

```
from tkinter import *

class Trip:
    def __init__(self, parent1):
        self.parent = parent1
        self.go = Frame(self.parent, width=500, height=450)
        self.go.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.go.grid_propagate(0)  # to reserve space required for frame
        menuButton = Button(self.go, text="Continue", command=self.menuScreen)
        menuButton.grid(row=1, column=0)


    def menuScreen(self):
        self.go.grid_remove()
        self.menu = Frame(self.parent, width=500, height=450, bg='orchid')
        self.menu.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.menu.grid_propagate(0)  # to reserve space required for frame

        self.addMore = Button(self.menuScreen, text="Return", command=self.__init__)
        self.addmore.grid(row=1, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Traveller Details")
    play = Trip(root)
    root.geometry("500x450+0+0")
    root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: As it stands, it is not possible to return from the second frame to the first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the two frames in `__init__` first; then show the tk window with the first frame.

A clickable button on each frame allows you to switch back and forth between the two frames.

```
"""
demonstrate switching back and forth between tkinter frames
"""

import tkinter as tk

class Trip:
    """
    A class to demonstrate switching back and forth between tkinter frames
    """

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Traveller Details")
        self.parent.geometry("500x450+0+0")        

        self.go_frame = tk.Frame(self.parent, width=500, height=450, bg='light blue')
        self.goto_menu_frame_button = tk.Button(self.go_frame, text="Continue", command=self.menu_screen)

        self.menu_frame = tk.Frame(self.parent, width=500, height=450, bg='light steel blue')
        self.goto_go_frame_button = tk.Button(self.menu_frame, text="Return", command=self.go_screen)

        self.current_frame = None
        self.go_screen()

    def go_screen(self):
        """
        The first screen to be visible - has a clickable button to switch 
        to the other screen 
        """
        self.remove_current_frame()
        self.current_frame = self.go_frame
        self.go_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.go_frame.grid_propagate(0)  # to reserve space required for frame
        self.goto_menu_frame_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def menu_screen(self):
        """
        The second screen - has a clickable button to switch back to the first screen 
        """
        self.remove_current_frame()
        self.current_frame = self.menu_frame
        self.menu_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.menu_frame.grid_propagate(0)  # to reserve space required for frame
        self.goto_go_frame_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def remove_current_frame(self):
        """
        removes the current frame from the grid if it exists
        """
        if self.current_frame is not None:
            self.current_frame.grid_remove()

    def start(self):
        """
        launches the GUI
        """
        self.parent.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trip = Trip(tk.Tk())
    trip.start()
```